# Given the data set is the Bayesian estimation the best solution for solving the expected value?

Tags: expectation, bayesian

I am very new to this. I have several measurements that from which I need to estimate a truth value.  Each of them comes with an estimated error. I know that the observation error are biased (I don't know the expected observation error). I want to find the expected value of this parameter. What is the best technique for calculate the best estimate? MLE will require the knowledge of the expected observation error. Is Bayesian estimation is the better one to use? If so, how should I approach it?

Comment: Your question is vague.  Do you mean you observe the value of the sum of the random variable of interest and an error (which would presumably be another random variable)?  "Biased" is a word that normally makes sense only when referring to observables used to estimate unobservables.  Which observables are you using to estimate which unobservables, when you say the errors are biased?  Might you mean only that the expected values of the errors are not zero?  MLEs don't in general require unbiasedness, but maybe you have in mind some particular context within which they do require that.

Comment: . . . but MLEs generally do require a family of probability distributions indexed by the thing whose MLE you seek.  Which such family do you have in mind?

Comment: I don't know how to say this. But I have multiple measurements of A from different instruments, each measurements comes with an error. The error is biased because certain observing conditions. My previous statement of "random values" is not proper.  What I mean random is that these measurements are assumed not correlated. About "bias" I do mean the expected values of the errors are not zero, since I don't know the instrument biases it will be hard for me to debias the Sa.